# Tailwind CSS: Background white '#F2F2F2' is not covering the whole screen when responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my react.js frontend, I have 2 columns (Dislay event list, create event) This is how my website look like in full screen.
[image: full screen]

However, when I tried to view it with smaller screen to test the responsiveness, the background white '#F2F2F2' is not showing for the 2nd column.

[image: smaller size to see responsiveness]

[image: with highlights]

How do I solve this issue?

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "../Components/customButton";
import KeyboardArrowLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft";
import TopicList from "../Components/topicList";
import EventList from "../Components/eventList";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

function CreateEvent(success, message) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [eventName, setEventName] = useState("");
    const [eventDesc, setEventDesc] = useState("");
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState("");
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("");
    const [multiplierType, setMultiplierType] = useState("");
    const [multiplier, setMultiplier] = useState("");
    const [topic, setTopic] = useState("");
    const [eventNameCharLeft, setEventNameCharLeft] = useState(100);
    const [eventDescCharLeft, setEventDescCharLeft] = useState(255);

    const getDataFromTopicList = (val) => {
        setTopic(val);
    };

    const handleEventNameChange = (event) => {
        setEventName(event.target.value);
        setEventNameCharLeft(100 - event.target.value.length);
    };

    const handleEventDescChange = (event) => {
        setEventDesc(event.target.value);
        setEventDescCharLeft(255 - event.target.value.length);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL + "events/submitEvent",
            data: {
                eventName: eventName,
                eventDesc: eventDesc,
                eventStart: startDate,
                eventEnd: endDate,
                topicId: topic,
                multiplierType: multiplierType,
                multiplier: multiplier,
                status: "Upcoming",
            },

            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    toast.success("Successfully Created", {
                        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                    });
                } else {
                    toast.error(response.data.message, {
                        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err.response) {
                    toast.error(err.response.data.message, {
                        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                    });
                } else {
                    toast.error("Failed to Create", {
                        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
                    });
                }
            });
    };

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen">
            <Button
                variant="primary"
                className="absolute top-4 left-6 px-0 py-2 font-bold btn btn-primary text-main-blue"
                onClick={() => {navigate(`/Admin`);}}
        isDisabled={false}
                buttonText="Back"
                icon={<KeyboardArrowLeftIcon color="main-green" />}
            />

            <div className=" grid grid-cols-2 p-20 space-x-8 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 h-screen lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-2 2xl:grid-cols-2"> 
                <div className="px-4 pt-4 pb-8 mb-4 bg-slate-50 drop-shadow-xl rounded-2xl">
                    {/* Ongoing Events */}
                    <h1 className="py-3 my-2 font-semibold border-b-2 text-main-blue border-main-blue">Ongoing Events</h1>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 pt-2 gap-x-10">
                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">Event Name</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">Start Date</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">End Date</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <EventList url="events/getOngoing" />

                    {/* Upcoming Events */}
                    <h1 className="py-3 my-2 font-semibold border-b-2 text-main-blue border-main-blue">Upcoming Events</h1>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 pt-2 gap-x-10">
                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">Event Name</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">Start Date</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-main-blue">End Date</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <EventList url="events/getUpcoming" />

                    {/* Past Events */}
                    <h1 className="py-3 my-2 font-semibold text-gray-400 border-b-2 border-gray-400">Past Events</h1>

                    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 pt-2 gap-x-10">
                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400">Event Name</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400">Start Date</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="">
                            <h1 className="pb-3 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400">End Date</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <EventList url="events/getPast" />
                </div>

                <form
                    className="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 rounded sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 bg-white" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold pt-15 text-main-blue">Create an Event</h1>
                    <div>
                        <textarea
                            className="block w-full px-5 py-2 mt-2 overflow-y-auto text-sm break-words border border-gray-300 rounded-md bg-slate-50 text-main-blue drop-shadow-lg"
                            name="eventName" placeholder="Event Name" required onChange={handleEventNameChange} value={eventName}maxLength={100}>
                        </textarea>
                        <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {eventNameCharLeft}/100 characters left
                        </div>
                        
                        <textarea
                            className="block w-full px-5 py-2 mt-2 overflow-y-auto text-sm break-words border border-gray-300 rounded-md bg-slate-50 text-main-blue drop-shadow-lg"
                            name="eventDesc" placeholder="Event Description" required onChange={handleEventDescChange} value={eventDesc} maxLength={255}>
                        </textarea>
                        <div className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {eventDescCharLeft}/255 characters left
                        </div>

                        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-2 mt-4">
                            <div className="relative">
                                <label className="absolute text-sm text-gray-500">Start Date</label>
                                <input
                                    className="bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border border-gray-300 drop-shadow-lg text-sm rounded-md my-5 block w-full p-2.5"
                                    type="datetime-local" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date" required onChange={(event) => setStartDate(event.target.value)} value={startDate}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="relative">
                                <label className="absolute text-sm text-gray-500">End Date</label>
                                <input
                                    className="bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border border-gray-300 drop-shadow-lg text-sm rounded-md my-5 block w-full p-2.5"
                                    type="datetime-local" name="endDate" placeholder="End Date" required onChange={(event) => setEndDate(event.target.value)} value={endDate}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-2">
                            <TopicList getDataFromTopicList={getDataFromTopicList} />
                            <select
                                className="bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border border-gray-300 drop-shadow-lg text-sm rounded-md block w-auto p-2.5"
                                name="multiplierType" required onChange={(event) => setMultiplierType(event.target.value)} value={multiplierType}>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Multiplier</option>
                                <option value="+">Add</option>
                                <option value="*">Multiply</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <input
                            className="bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border border-gray-300 drop-shadow-lg text-sm rounded-md my-5 block w-full p-2.5"
                            type="number" name="multiplier" placeholder="Multiplier Value (Eg 1-100)" min="1" max="100" required onChange={(event) => setMultiplier(event.target.value)} value={multiplier}/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="relative p-4">
                        <Button
                            variant="primary"
                            className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 px-4 py-2 -my-5 font-bold border rounded btn btn-primary bg-slate-50 text-main-blue border-main-blue hover:border-transparent hover:bg-main-blue hover:text-slate-50"
                            isDisabled={false}
                            buttonText="Submit"
                            type="submit"
                        />
                        <ToastContainer autoClose={4000} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateEvent;
```

This is the output for small screen in tailwind playground.
[image: tailwind playground]

Comment: Please produce code in question or provide the [tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) code.

Comment: `h-screen` will cover the height of the viewport. On mobile it scrolls so the height of the page will be greater than the height of the viewport.

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I have added the code here. You may now take a look.

Comment: @yaakov so what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Where is `#F2F2F2` in your code ?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya tailwind config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine for me !

##### Code Link:  [tailwind_playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aNguIXYTUf)

##### Output in large screen:

[image]

##### Output in small screen:

[image]

Comment: This is what it looks like for me in tailwind playground. I added the image in the content

Comment: Does it help ? What further changes are you looking for?

Comment: No, I have added the screenshot of my screen in the tailwind playground link you sent. The background did not cover the small screen output.

Comment: Send me the tailwind playground link which you have worked out and you are facing problem. In the top left corner there is share button . Click that and send the link to me

Comment: It is the same link that you have provided with your answer, here is the link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aNguIXYTUf

Comment: It is working perfectly fine in that link. What problems are you facing can you be more specific , I cannot see any error in that link. The background color occupies full screen even when the screen is small as shown in the output of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "h-screen" in the class name on the element you have selected in your screenshot. This prevents it from extending to the height of the elements inside it. You can change this to "min-h-screen" as well however, I would recommend just removing it entirely.

Comment: I removed the h-screen but the issue is still not fixed

Comment: You have an additional "h-screen" on the parent element, try removing that as well or changing it to "min-h-screen"

Comment: I changed the parent element to min-h-screen and removed the h-screen for others but It did not change anything.

Comment: if you don't mind it you could always set the body background to #F2F2F2 if the whole page is meant to be that color